# Set model properties from textbox value in ASP NET CORE 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to pass my model to a partial view, but I'm not sure how to set model properties with input data from form controls.

```
@model ChartViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Charts";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Chart", "Chart", FormMethod.Get))
{
    var typeList = Html.GetEnumSelectList<TypeEnumeration>();
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.SymbolId);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.TypeId,typeList);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.NearDate);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.FarDate);
    
    <partial name="_ShowChartButtonPartial" model="Model.ShowChartButtonDTO" />
}
@Html.Raw(Model.Renderer.RenderHtml())
```

When I run the application and click the button, the default model properties from initial initiazation is passed, not the values from textboxes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the application and click the button, the default model properties from initial initiazation is passed, not the values from textboxes.

`model="Model.ShowChartButtonDTO"` will not be change with inputs,it is c# model.And you can try to use ajax to change the partial view.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class ChartViewModel {
        public ShowChartButtonDTO ShowChartButtonDTO { get; set; }
    }
    public class ShowChartButtonDTO {
        public int SymbolId { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        
        public List<SelectListItem> typeList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" } };
        public string NearDate { get; set; }
        public string FarDate { get; set; }


    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Chart", "Chart", FormMethod.Get))
{
    var typeList = Html.GetEnumSelectList<TypeEnumeration>();
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.SymbolId, new { @class = "change" });
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.TypeId, typeList, new { @class = "change" });
    @*<input type="date" id="ShowChartButtonDTO_NearDate"/>*@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.NearDate, new { @class = "change",@type= "date" });
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShowChartButtonDTO.FarDate, new { @class = "change" });
<div id="partial">
    <partial name="_ShowChartButtonPartial" model="Model.ShowChartButtonDTO" />
</div>
    
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("input[class='change']").change(function () {
            var model = {
                ShowChartButtonDTO: {
                    SymbolId: parseInt($("#ShowChartButtonDTO_SymbolId").val()),
                    TypeId: parseInt($("#ShowChartButtonDTO_TypeId").val()),
                    NearDate: $("#ShowChartButtonDTO_NearDate").val(),
                    FarDate: $("#ShowChartButtonDTO_NearDate").val()

                }
            };
                 $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Partial")',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: model,
                }).done(function(result) {
                    $('#partial').html(result);
                });
            
        })
      
    </script>

}
```

action:

```
public IActionResult Partial(ChartViewModel chartViewModel)
        {
            return PartialView("_ShowChartButtonPartial",chartViewModel);
        }
```